# why should listIterator parameter be final in source code of AbstractList?

Tags: java, list, api

when I view source code of java API,I just can't understand why this parameter should be final?

```
    public ListIterator<E> listIterator(final int index) {
    rangeCheckForAdd(index);

    return new ListItr(index);
}
```

This is 324th line of AbstractList.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`final` there means that the method cannot change the value of the parameter. This is useful primarily as in-code documentation/restriction, making the compiler turn an attempt to modify it into an error. It may also be useful information for the compiler and/or JVM to have for optimization purposes; e.g., they don't have to apply static analysis to see whether the parameter is never changed, you've forced that to be true. This may be particularly useful information when *inlining* the method call when it's called with a constant value, such as in the implementation of [`listIterator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#listIterator--) (with no parameters), which is simply: `return listIterator(0);`.

Comment: Is it just for optimization purposes?And if it isn't final,this parameter will not lead to any problem?

Comment: @zhaoch93: Again, also in-code documentation. No, there'd be no problem if it weren't `final`. I don't know whether that might change the optimizations the compiler and/or JVM can apply, or whether they'd just have to work harder first (figuring out that it's never changed).